# Why is my button working even though I haven't assigned any parent window to it?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-button

Why is my button working even though I haven't assigned any parent window to it?

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

Button(text='MyButton').pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Tkinter widgets default to being a child of the root window, if you don't explicitly give a parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Widgets live in a tree-like hierarchy with a single widget acting as the root of the tree. The root widget is an instance of `Tk` and should be explicitly created by the application before any other widget.

All widgets except the root window require a master. If you do not explicitly define the master for a widget it will default to using the root window.

You can turn this behavior off by calling the function `NoDefaultRoot` from the tkinter module. For example, the following code will fail with `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tk'`:

```
from tkinter import *

NoDefaultRoot()

root = Tk()
Button(text='MyButton').pack() 
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Um sorry but what do you mean when you say the root window , does that mean the only window which I have created ?

Comment: @AyushSingh: widgets exist in a tree-like hierarchy which must have a single widget as the root. This will be the first instance of `Tk` that is created, either explicitly or implicitly.